# Outlook scripting in C#?

Tags: outlook, scripting, outlook-addin

I'm using Outlook 2010.  Via the Developer ribbon, I see that I'm able to script Outlook using VBA.  I'm also aware that you can create Outlook addins through COM that can pretty much have anything as their source language (C# / .NET included).

However, is there any way to actually code extensions to Outlook using *built-in* Outlook functionality using C#, rather than VBA?  If not, are there any plans for Microsoft to allow this in future versions of Outlook?

Comment: Googled this because VBA sucks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "built in" functionality. Addin can access anything VBA can access AFAIK.

Are you talking about converting the VBA editor to c sharp?

Comment: Yes, basically; instead of having to "install" an addin with a setup file, being able to just copy/paste code into an internal Outlook editor, like one can with VBA at the moment.

Comment: Never heard of any plans for this. VBA will be around a while in the future, because it's still the Microsoft approach for "power-users" to automate small tasks, however without the ability to deploy a solution to other users in a manageable way. - All other automation will go through COM add-ins and a deployment through a setup procedure.

Comment: Aside from VBA being an extremely nasty programming language for those of us used to other stuff (not to mention the built-in IDE being an utterly horrible thing from the 1990s), the real problem is that it seems to totally lack .NET support, which really limits what you can do with it.  It's disappointing if this situation is not to be improved.